# Dynamic import of JavaScript module without file path

Tags: javascript, dynamic-import, virtualfilesystem

Is it possible in the ECMAScript language, or other way, to import a module using some kind of object **other than the real file path in local computer** (whether relative or absolute, or with an "import map")?

For example, as a use-case, there are some JavaScript packages ("memfs") that mimic files and behave like virtual filesystems. Some of those files can of course contain JS code that can play the role of a JS Module, possibly wanted to be **dynamically imported**. They may have a "fake" virtual file path or file name, but how can the JS Runtime/Parser/Interpreter can process it?

Also, we can simply read a local file's content (Via NodeJS for example), and it's possible that we want to load its content as a module, when the original path is not available anymore, or for any other reason.

So, sometimes you have files, file contents, but without "file path", how it's possible to use that content for a module? (and not a regular inline scoped object.

Comment: If you mean `node.js`, then yes, you can intercept the require calls, that's how things like `ts-node` work.  If you mean the browser, again this is also possible by registering a serviceWorker and intercept the fetch requests.

Comment: @Keith could you show how it's possible? Also, I'd love to be more specific to something like ECMAScript standard or compatible, or Deno. Also, what about "https://github.com/denoland/deno_emit"?

Comment: How modules are loaded in Node / Browser & Deno are all different, as such you really need to be more specfic.